# In golang why I can't use the struct as nested struct type?

Tags: go, interface, type-conversion, embedding

The following code ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/Uwr_TzM5OB)):

```
func main() {
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0))
    rw := bufio.NewReadWriter(bufio.NewReader(buf), bufio.NewWriter(buf))
    var r *bufio.Writer
    r = rw
}
```

Gives the following compile-time error:

```
cannot use rw (type *bufio.ReadWriter) as type *bufio.Writer in assignment
```

What I expected is use a struct as a nested struct type. But if I declare `r` as `io.Reader`, this will be ok, so should I move to interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`bufio.NewReadWriter()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewReadWriter) returns a concrete type, a pointer to a `struct` and [`bufio.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Writer) is also a concrete type, a `struct`. Neither `*ReadWriter` and `*bufio.Writer` is an [interface](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)!

In Go there is no automatic type conversion, you cannot assign a value of different concrete type to a variable.

#### You have 2 options:

1. Since `bufio.ReadWriter` embeds `*bufio.Writer`, you can simply refer to it and use that in the assignment:

   ```
   var r *bufio.Writer
   r = rw.Writer
   ```
2. Or you can declare `r` to be an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) (it is an interface type) so that you can assign `rw` to it because `rw` implements `io.Writer`:

   ```
   var r io.Writer
   r = rw
   ```

   Although I don't think creating `r` in this case is particularly useful because whenever you would use `r` you could also use `rw`.

Check out [Go spec: Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability):

> A value `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> - `x`'s type is identical to `T`.
> - `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical underlying types and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a named type.
> - `T` is an interface type and `x` implements `T`.
> - `x` is a bidirectional channel value, `T` is a channel type, `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical element types, and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a named type.
> - `x` is the predeclared identifier `nil` and `T` is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - `x` is an untyped constant representable by a value of type `T`.

None of the cases apply to your code, so it is an invalid assignment.

When `r` is declared to be `io.Writer`, it is the the following case and therefore it is valid:

> `T` is an interface type and `x` implements `T`.

Comment: Why isn't a bufio reader and writer an interface in the first place?

Answer (score -3):

Different type can't assign, GO do not support extension.